# Prove whether this function is an injection, surjection, bijection or neither.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The function is written as follows $p:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where $p(a,b)=(ab(b+1))/2$

So far I tried supposing that $p(a_1, b_1) = p(a_2,b_2)$ but I couldn't reach a conclusion when I subbed it back into the equation. Thanks for the help!

0 is not considered a natural.

Comment: Let a=1, b=2. Then let a=3, b=1. What does this tell you about injectivity?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than votes to close or downvotes if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you were stuck. Show us even what didn't work. (Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: @OP Do you consider 0 a natural number?

Answer (score 0):

Simce, for each $a\in\mathbb N$,$$p\left(\frac{a(a+1)}2,1\right)=p(1,a),$$your function is far from injective. It is surjective, though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$ P(10,2)=P(2,5)=30$$

Thus it is not injective.

However, it is surjective  because $$P(n,1)=n$$

for all natural numbers $ n.$

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes intuition is just great.  But what if you don't have it?

For surjective:

If $n = \frac {ab(b+1)}2$ then $a = \frac {2n}{b(b+1)}$ which can be solved be solved if we can find $b(b+1)|2n$.  We could do $b(b+1) = m$ where $m|2n$ and solve with the quadratic formula that $b^2 + b -m = 0$ so $b =\frac {-1\pm\sqrt{1+4m}}{2}$ so $1+4m$ must be an odd perfect square greater than $1$ and $m|2n$ and... well the simplest such case considering we don't really know anything about $n$ would be if $m = 2$ (and $m$ must divide $2n$) and $b =\{-2, 1\}$ so $b= 1$.  And $a = \frac {2n}{1(1+1)} = n$

So $f(n, 1) = n$ for all $n$ so surjective.

And then we kick ourselves for not seeing that that was obvious.

Now injective.

If we have intution and we just saw that that $f(n,1) = n$; so.... then $f(a,b) = f(f(a,b), 1)$.  And so long as $b \ne 1$, we have $(f(a,b), 1) \ne (a,b)$. So $f$ is not injective.

[This assumes $f(a,b) \in \mathbb N$ for all $(a,b)$.  In other words that $f$ actually *IS* a well-defined function.  As either $b$ or $b+1$ is even then the $\frac {b(b+1)}2$ is a natural number.  And so $f(a,b) = \frac{ab(b+1)}2$ is a natural number.]

But what if we didn't have the intuition?

If $\frac{ab(b+1)}2 = \frac {cd(d+1)}2$

$ab(b+1) = cd(d+1)$.

Surely there are examples where $a\ne c; b\ne d$.

Fix $b, d$ so $b\ne d$ then $a*M = c*N$ where $M = b(b+1)$ and $N=d(d+1)$.  Solving $a*M = c*N$ should be easy.

For example, just let $a =N$ and $c = M$ so $a*M= c*N =N*M$.  Or, more generally, for any multiple of $gcd(N,M)$ we can have $a*M = c*N = k*\gcd(N,M)$ by setting $a = \frac {kN}{\gcd(N,M)}$ and $c = \frac {kM}{\gcd(N,M)}$.

So $f$ is not injective.

Just to be thorough...

When we were trying to show surjectivity we consider $b =\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4m}}2$  where $m|2n$.  If $1+ 4m$ is any odd perfect square and $m|2n$ we have a solution.  So if we let $m = 2, 6, 12, 20,30,42,$ etc. we will have  solutions.  So if $n$ has two or more $1,3,6,10, 15, 21,$ etc. as factors,  we will have two or more solutions.

Example: if $n = 60$ we can have $m|120; m = 2,6,12, 20, 30,  b = 1,2, 3, 4, 5$ and $a= 60, 20, 10, 6, 4$ so $60 = f(60,1)=f(20,2)=f(10,3) = f(6,4)= f(4,5)$.